# из С-строки в QString

Tags: c++, c, qt

Как скопировать *N* символов С-строки в `QString` без использования циклов?

Comment: str[size] = 0x00, потом смело присваивайте в QString. Никаких циклов!

Comment: можно скопировать все, а потом через [left](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#left)

Comment: Если вкратце, то RTFM :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
auto qs = QString::fromLatin1(cstr, N);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
const char* cStr = "Hello world!";
int N = 5;
QString qStr(QLatin1String(cStr , N));
```